# data convert to data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I have a text file that I need to converted into a list. Here's the data form text file:

```
'ID=s4k5jk\nDate=8 December 1970\nTitle=crossing the atlantic on a tricycle\nID=f983\nDate=22 December 1970\nTitle=Royal Episode 13'
```

I need an output in the form of a list that looks like this

```
l = [
 #ID               Date               Title        
["s4k5jk", "8 December 1970", "crossing the atlantic on a tricycle"],
["f983",   "22 December 1970",   "Royal Episode 13"]]
```

Can someone could let me know how to convert this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: @zondo my desired result is to print a list L(see above output), I just added the original data from the text file

Comment: That isn't a dictionary; that's a list. Is that what you want?

Comment: I edited your question to say "list" instead of "dictionary". Let me know if that's OK.

Comment: yes, it is okay. Thank you! I am still new to Python learning... @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each item is defined by its `"ID="`, I used this term to `split()` the initial sentence.

Then was just a matter of `splitting` each sentence at `"\n"`, manipulating a few strings and `appending` them to a `list` called `results`.

**Code:**

```
s = 'ID=s4k5jk\nDate=8 December 1970\nTitle=crossing the atlantic on a tricycle\nID=f983\nDate=22 December 1970\nTitle=Royal Episode 13'

data = s.split("\nID=")
results = []

for d in data:  
    res = d.split("\n")

    _id = res[0].replace("ID=", "")
    _date = res[1].replace("Date=", "")
    _title = res[2].replace("Title=", "")

    results.append([_id, _date, _title])

for r in results:
    print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
['s4k5jk', '8 December 1970', 'crossing the atlantic on a tricycle']
['f983', '22 December 1970', 'Royal Episode 13']
```

Comment: data = s.split("ID=") is better since it allows for the very first entry to be accounted for as well. 
But in this version of the solution, go from "for d in data[1:]"

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a regex approach:

```
>>> print(s)
ID=s4k5jk
Date=8 December 1970
Title=crossing the atlantic on a tricycle
ID=f983
Date=22 December 1970
Title=Royal Episode 13
>>> fields = re.findall(r'ID=([\s\S]+?)\sDate=([\s\S]+?)\sTitle=([\s\S]+?)$', s, re.MULTILINE)
>>> fields
[('s4k5jk', '8 December 1970', 'crossing the atlantic on a tricycle'), ('f983', '22 December 1970', 'Royal Episode 13')]
>>>
```

Note, using the capture groups works exactly as one would hope with `re.findall`!